# check if any form element are filled

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

I had one form with inputs, chechbox, radio button, textarea.
I would like to check with jquery if any of element of my form are filled, if at least one field is filled, then ok.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#form_id").submit(function() {
    var filled = false;
    $(this).find("input").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
           filled = true;
        }
    });
    if (filled) { return true; }
    else { // raise an error
           return false; }
});
```

Essentially, just loop through the input fields and see if any are not empty.  If the jQuery submit handler returns true, then the default behavior of the form occurs (it submits) and if it returns false, then nothing will happen.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
if ($('input:checked, input[type="text"][value!=""], textarea[value!=""]) {
    // some form field is filled
}
```

`input:checked` looks for checked checkboxes or radio buttons, `input[type="text"][value!=""]` looks for text input fields whose value is not an empty string, and `textarea:not(:empty)` selects textareas that have some text within them (even if that's just whitespace).  The selector selects all these elements and then `.length` checks whether any elements were matched by these checks.

Comment: @codethis That isn't in the specification, but yes, `input[type="password"][value!=""]` could be added if desired.

Comment: You'll want to test the `value` of the `textarea` instead of the HTML content (assuming OP wants to check for user modification). Changes the user made are reflected by the `value` property.